# PNG optimization and environment impact

Tags: image, optimization, png

PNG can be optimized in different ways.

Reducing PNG size for websites seems to be a good choice in order to reduce bandwidth usage and data transport and reduce the impact on environment. It's recommended by Google and other services.

But does optimize PNG have an impact on CPU load when the computer read it to render it? In other words, is reducing PNG size to optimize size a good idea to limit environment impact?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> does optimize PNG have an impact on CPU load when the computer read it to render it? In other words, is reducing PNG size to optimize size a good idea to limit environment impact?

I'm not sure that one question follows from the other, but, regarding the first one:

No, the effort to optimize the PNG compression, so as to make the image smaller, only impacts on the compressor side. In the client (decompressor) side, the difference on speed or CPU usage is practically zero.

To be more precise: PNG compression is mainly influenced by two factors: the "pixel filtering" algorithm/strategy (PNG specific) and the ZLIB compression level. Optimizing the first one has no effect on the decompression 
(the "unfiltering" logic is one and the same). The second factor, also, has little or no influence on decompression speed ([it might even be slightly beneficious](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28452429/does-gzip-compression-level-have-any-impact-on-decompression)).

Comment: Thanks! "I'm not sure that one question follows from the other" :) You are right!

Answer (score 1):

As @leonbloy stated in his answer, the zlib compression level has little or no effect on the decompression speed.  The PNG filter selection does, however, have a noticeable effect: the AVG and PAETH filters both require more memory and CPU time to defilter than do the simpler ones.

Libpng allows you to control this via the "png_set_filter()" function.  For maximum compression with adaptive filtering, use

```
png_set_filter(write_ptr, 0, PNG_ALL_FILTERS);
```

while to avoid the slower AVG and PAETH filtering, use

```
png_set_filter(write_ptr, 0, PNG_NONE_FILTER|PNG_SUB_FILTER|PNG_UP_FILTER);
```

or with libpng-1.6.22 and later, you can more conveniently use

```
png_set_filter(write_ptr, 0, PNG_FAST_FILTERS);
```

With pngcrush-1.8.1 or later, you can use

```
pngcrush -speed file.png file_pc.png
```

to select the NONE, SUB, and UP filters but avoid AVG and PAETH
(note that pngcrush also has a "-fast" option, but that is for a different purpose, namely to select fast compression methods).

When the intended use of the output is to transmit over the net to an application, the file size is the dominant effect and you'd want to use maximum compression.  But when the file will be accessed from your local disc
or from memory, then the decoding speed is dominant and you'd want to use "speed" optimization which will trade off some increased file size for faster decoding.